# Number of Characters in a pointer of unsigned chars in C

Tags: c

I have a function that concatenates characters in a pointer and I need to return its size, but I can not get the total of characters, this is the function:

```
int function(unsigned char * dest)
{
    *dest++ = 0x12;
    *dest++ = 0x34;
    *dest++ = 0x56;
    *dest++ = 0x78;
    *dest++ = 0x9A;
    *dest++ = 0xBC;
    *dest++ = 0xDE;
    *dest++ = 0xFF;

    *dest++ = '\0';

    size_t len = strlen((char*) dest);

    return len;
}
```

This is how I occupy it:

```
unsigned char buffer[512];
int buffer_len = function(buffer);
```

The problem is that `buffer_len` is always zero and i expect to be 16.

Comment: `strlen()` expects a pointer to the start of the string, not 1 past its `\0` terminator...

Comment: Call `strlen(buffer)` after `function` returns.  What do you get from _that_? Then look again at how you are using `dest`, and in particular think about what `++` does.

Comment: If you call `strlen((char*) dest)` then `dest` points just behind all the added characters. Copy `dest` before modifying it and call `strlen()` for that second pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get to the `strlen` call, `dest` is pointing to one element past the null byte at the end of the string.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since that byte and the ones after were never initialized.

You need to keep track of the original value of `dest` and subtract:

```
int function(unsigned char * dest)
{
    unsigned char *start = dest;
    *dest++ = 0x12;
    *dest++ = 0x34;
    *dest++ = 0x56;
    *dest++ = 0x78;
    *dest++ = 0x9A;
    *dest++ = 0xBC;
    *dest++ = 0xDE;
    *dest++ = 0xFF;

    *dest = '\0';

    return dest - start;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

You are modifying the input pointer `dest` that you've passed as a parameter.

At the point of calling `strlen((char*) dest)`, `dest` points to one past the NUL that you added. You cannot then predict the behaviour of `strlen` as it will be reading uninitialised elements of `buffer`.

The simplest fix is to take a copy of `dest` when you enter the function, and subract that original value from the final value of `dest`. That will be the string length.